# Collecting relationships from pairs of strings in lists

Tags: python, logic

Consider the below set of lists that contain two strings each.

The pairing of two strings in a given list means the values they represent are equal. So item A is the same as item B and C, and so on.

```
l1 = [ 'A' , 'B' ] 
l2 = [ 'A' , 'C' ]
l3 = [ 'B' , 'C' ]
```

What is the most efficient/pythonic way to collect these relationships into a dict such as the one below:

```
{ "A" : [ "B" , "C" ] }
```

p.s. Apologies for the poor title, I did not know how to describe the problem!

**EDIT:**

To make the problem clearer, I am trying to filter out duplicated samples from thousands of records.

I have pairwise comparisons for each sample in the data set which indicate if they are a duplicate of one another.

Sometimes a sample may appear in the data set in triplicate/quadruplicate with a different identifier.

It is important to keep just ONE of the duplicated samples.

Hence wanting a dict or similar structure which contains the selected sample as a key, and a list of its duplicates in the dataset as values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a rather long-winded answer that stores an ID if it has been added to the dict already.

There must be a more efficient answer though!

```
l = [["A", "B"], ["A", "C"], ["B", "C"]]

d = dict()
used_list = list()

for i in l:
    id_one, id_two = i

    if not id_one in used_list and id_one not in d.keys():

        d[id_one] = [id_two]
        used_list.append(id_two)
        continue

    if not id_one in used_list and id_one in d.keys():
        d[id_one].append(id_two)
        used_list.append(id_two)

print( d )
```

Returns:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C']}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a defaultdict from collections so the dictionary expands and just takes whatever you throw into it.  If this is a one way correspondence I would use this code (assuming you make a list of the lists)

```
dd = collections.defaultdict(list)

for line in lists:
    dd[line[0]].append(line[1])
```

for given set this will make dictionaries

```
{"A" : ["B", "C"] }
{"B" : ["C"] }
'''
this should be a good starting point
```

Answer (score 1):

---

Assuming you can get a list of those lists like so:

```
[[ 'A' , 'B' ], [ 'A' , 'C' ],[ 'B' , 'C' ]]
```

This should give you the relation you want:

```
d = {}

l1 = [[ 'A' , 'B' ],[ 'A' , 'C' ],[ 'B' , 'C' ]] 

for sublist in l1:
    if sublist[0] not in d.keys(): #check if first value is already a key in the dict
        d[sublist[0]] = [] #init new key with empty list
    d[sublist[0]].append(sublist[1]) #append second value
```

output:

```
{'A': ['B', 'C'], 'B': ['C']}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The aim is to not have the 'B': ['C'] captured in the dict as B and C are both equal to A.

Comment: This is a very make-shift answer, but you could perform a check to see if both of the values reside in any of the already established relations. For example, before appending `['B','C']` you could check if both of these are in `{'A':['B','C']}` and append if they're not. Note: you would have to check both the key and the key's corresponding values, so you'll need to unpack that relation somehow. I'll add another answer if I figure it out.